# Checking if a particular character in another string (at particular index)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

The function has 2 parameters:

1. the string that is the individual
2. the string that is the target I am trying to match
   and counts and returns the number of matching characters in the same positions(e.g. "ABC" has 1 match with "ACB")
   However the count does not come correct for the test words: evalFit('ABC BA','ABCABC',) which should be 4.

The code:

```
def evalFit(indv,target):
  count = 0
  for charac in target:
    if charac == indv[target.index(charac)]:
        count += 1
  return count
```

Comment: `target.index(charac)` is the position of the *first* instance of the character in the string, not necessarily the instance you're currently iterating over.  Write the loop as `for idx, character in enumerate(target):` to get both the actual index and the character; you can then test `charac == target[idx]`.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be an easy task for `zip()` and `sum()`. Look:

```py
def eval_fit(A, B):
    return sum(1 for (a, b) in zip(A, B) if a == b)


print(eval_fit('ABC BA','ABCABC'))
```

The code above will result in:

```py
4
```

In the code above, `zip()` create pairs of characters at the same position in each string. Then, using a comprehension to check which pairs have matching characters, we create a counting assigning `1` for each matching pair, and finally we return the `sum()` of those `1`s list.

And here is what `zip()` does:

```py
>>> list(zip('ABC BA','ABCABC'))
[('A', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C'), (' ', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('A', 'C')]
```